# Cannot read properties of null (reading 'addEventListener') in a Javascript file (not script tag)

Tags: javascript, html, typeerror

I am a JavaScript beginner and when I was making a HTML, CSS, JS project with VSCode, I encountered the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading at 'addEventListener')

Also, My project was: Make a login + register system with just JavaScript dictionaries, and a logged_in variable (that will redirect people to the registration page if it's false)

HTML Registration file:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset='utf-8'>
    <meta http-equiv='X-UA-Compatible' content='IE=edge'>
    <title>BeedHub Register</title>
    <meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1'>
    <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' media='screen' href='style.css'>
    <script src='index.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1 class="hello_world">Welcome!</h1>
    <p class="aaa">We're so excited to see you!</p>
    <div class="usernamediv">
        <input id="main_usr" placeholder="Write username here" type="text">
    </div>
    <div class="passworddiv">
        <input id="main_pw" placeholder="Write password here" type="password">
    </div>
    <div class="btn">
        <button id="main_register">Register!</button>
    </div>
    <div class="login_instead">
        <a href="C:\Users\directory\.vscode\directory\directory\directory\login">Login Instead</a>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

JavaScript file:

```js
// Variables
var db = {

};
var logged_in = false;

// Register Elements
var rg_usr = document.getElementById("main_usr");
var rg_pw = document.getElementById("main_pw");
var rg_submit = document.getElementById("main_register");

// Event Listeners
rg_submit.addEventListener('click',function() {
    if (db[rg_usr.innerHTML]) {
        var error_usr_taken = document.createElement("p");
        error_usr_taken.innerHTML = "Error: Username Already Taken!";
    } else if (rg_usr.innerHTML == "" || null) {
        var error_usr_none = document.createElement("p");
        error_usr_none.innerHTML = "Error: Username is null!";
    } else if (rg_pw.innerHTML == "" || null) {
        var error_pw_none = document.createElement("p");
        error_pw_none.innerHTML = "Error: Password is null!";
    } else {
        db[rg_usr.innerHTML] = rg_pw.innerHTML;
        logged_in = true;
        window.location.pathname = "/successpage";
    };
});
```

If you want me to provide more information, comment with a ping.

**P.S. I have also used the script tag on my /login/index.html file, but the web says that multiple HTML files using the same JavaScript file have no problem.**

Thanks in advance,

Beedful

Comment: You're trying to add a listener to an element that hasn't been formed. Move `<script src='index.js'></script>` to just before the `</body>` tag so the document can load. There are other ways to approach this but this is the quickest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your script is being executed before the markup is on the page and that's why you're getting an error.

So, you can either move the `script` tag at the very end of the `body` like this:

```
<body>
    <!-- All contents here -->
    <script src='index.js'></script>
</body>
```

Or you can add `defer` to your script tag and let it continue to be in the `head`, like this:

```
<script src='index.js' defer></script>
```

Comment: Still getting the error in my case. So weird